# Easiest way to read QR codes

Tags: ros, tracking, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying to use the hector_qrcode_detection_package to read QR codes, but I am having trouble getting it to run.  Is this package the easiest way to read QR codes?  If not, what other one should I be looking into?

If the hector package is the best and easiest way, can somebody please give me a more step-by-step method of getting it to run?

I'm running the hydro distribution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206432/easiest-way-to-read-qr-codes/) by [npp1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/22057/npp1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use `zbar_ros`
(http://wiki.ros.org/zbar_ros)

just need to google it, as I know, `hector_qrcode_detection` is based on this package.

---

Originally posted by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) with karma: 224 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1